# How to implement authentication in JBoss AS7 without Standalone.xml

Tags: xml, jboss, ldap, jboss7.x

I'm working in an environment where we have a lot of projects with different LDAP authentication databases, and I'm looking to find a way to define our authentication inside of the project, instead of using the server standalone.xml.

I've already created a jboss-web.xml and defined it in there like;

```
<jboss-web>
     <security-domain>ldapServerHere</security-domain>
     <context-root>RootIsHere</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

But I was looking for a way to define the authentication login-module XML outside of standalone. So that I can have a different file for each project I'm working on.

If anyone has any advice it'd be much appreciated. I've been searching on google for hours and haven't had much luck in the matter.

Thanks!

Justin

Answer (score 0):

If you want to step away from container managed security, you should look at application managed security frameworks, like [Spring Security.](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/index.html)